# How insert new object after update entity in Doctrine 2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I want save new entity after update object (Save history data).

I try add object to EntityManager and flush in preUpdate event, but i have recursion effect.

Comment: Be more clear when asking questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling `EntityManager#flush` within a lifecycle event: this is not supported and it will obviously lead to infinite recursion problems.